# How to use AtomicInteger getAndSet correctly?

Tags: java, java-stream, atomicinteger

I want to get the difference between consecutive list elements using Java stream and AtomicInteger:

```
List<Integer> list  = List.of(1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,22,23,27);
AtomicInteger diff  = new AtomicInteger(1);


List<Integer> result = list.stream()
                           .skip(1)
                           .map(i -> diff.getAndSet(i - diff.get()))
                           .toList();

System.out.println(result);
```

Output is:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 16, 7]
```

I was expecting to get the difference of each element from previous like below:

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 12, 1, 4]
```

What am I doing wrong? How to get the desired output?

Comment: If `diff` contains the difference, you are not calculating the difference to the previous value, but the difference to the the difference. What you actually want is, `.map(i -> i - diff.getAndSet(i))` though then, you should rename `diff` to `previous` to match the true purpose. However, that’s only to explain what’s wrong with the way you use the `AtomicInteger`, the answer suggesting to use a stream of indices instead, is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use an atomic type for this.  Instead I would start with a stream of the list indexes:

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 1)
                       .map(i -> list.get(i + 1) - list.get(i))
                       .boxed()
                       .toList();
```

Note that the ending number passed to [`IntStream#range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) is *exclusive* while the start is inclusive. The range is half-open.

This (IMO) is simpler and cleaner (and more functional) than relying on side-effects.

Comment: Thank you. I had obsessed myself with working with the elements and didn't think it would be easier to work with the indexes.